# Ways to prevent a class file from looking verbose when using multiple properties

Tags: c#, properties

Assume I have a (base)class that can `set` multiple `public` properties. The "public" (classes that aren't derived from this class) is only allowed to `get` these properties.

In code:

```
1.| /// <summary>
2.| /// Lorum Ipsum Factum Foobum...
3.| /// </summary>
4.| public object Foo
5.| {
6.|     get;
7.|     protected set;
8.| }
9.|
```

This takes 9 lines of boilerplate code. If you have a class file with many of these properties it becomes very cluttered<sup>1</sup>.

I can refactor it to three lines, like in the code sample below. But when dealing with many properties it's still an eyesore<sup>2</sup>.

```
1| /// <summary> Lorum Ipsum Factum Foobum. </summary>
2| public object Foo{ get; protected set;}
3|
```

I can place them in a region, but I find regions have problems of their own (IME these kind of regions are seldom collapsed while coding and they require auxilary work, IE: you expand the region, scroll down, examine/alter something, scroll up and collapse the region again).

So my question is:

**Are there other ways to reduce the verbosity of a class file when dealing with multiple properties?<sup>3 4</sup>**

---

<sup>1</sup> Not being able to come up with a better word, this question assumes that the "clutter" of a file is proportional to the lines of codes.

<sup>2</sup> IMHO of course, if you love the sight of neatly alligned properties, then I am sorry if I offended you ;)

<sup>3</sup> I can imagine exiling all these properties to a partial class file, but I have never seen a partial class being used as a property heap, so I am not sure this is regarded as good practice.

<sup>4</sup> Or perhaps doing something "neat" with the compiler.

Comment: Why? I understand that those are for "peer reviews", I have a question regarding the C# language.

Comment: Maybe you are searching for a sort of *preprocessor* ? I am using regions to hide something (to example, interops or a small code inside big static data class, etc). Otherwise I split class into few, to example, `Config-Code`, `Config-Appearance`, `Config-...`, which are same `partial class`. Less aesthetic people (those what came from Borland IDE's or after Visual Basic) don't care much about formatting, but are using method/property drop-down list (which exists in MSVS IDE) to browse to where they need. Also, you don't have to put every single property into region, you can put them all in 1.

Comment: @Sinatr, I looked at preprocessors, but the #define in C# doesn't work as it would in c/c++. And yes, I currently have all my properties in one region ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ get; set; }` is about as condensed as it gets.  Keep your class definitions in separate files from your logic to keep verbosity to a minimum.

One thing to note as well:  Visual Studio has a lot of solutions when working with large quantities of models/data.

If you are using data from a pre-existing database, you could look into a LINQ-to-SQL .dbml, which essentially eliminates the need to define your model objects entirely, letting you focus on only custom classes and objects.  The use of this, of course, depends on the specifications of your project though.

**Update:** Another thing: if you have a lot of "similar" (very loosely define) classes with like methods and are concerned about the space that individual classes would take up, you can take a look at polymorphism http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx.  You'll grab performance gains too from fewer new objects in memory at a given time.

Comment: So using partial classes are okay in this case?

Comment: Straight from msdn re: when to use partial classes: `When working on large projects, spreading a class over separate files enables multiple programmers to work on it at the same time.`  You should use them as much as possible IMO.

Comment: Partial classes are indeed very useful, but it should be noted that there is additional maintenance overhead involved.  Two scenarios to consider : If we split out to partials and you add a new property, you have to ensure you (or a team member) adds it to the correct file.  Also, when it comes to tracking down a bug, it can be a painful experience to have to constantly switch files to find the code you are looking for.  I'm not saying don't use partials - I *am* saying "have a strategy for using them and stick to it"